# How to write a sql query for following business logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three following three tables,

**1.** **ItemProdCodeValueMapping** (ItemId and ProdCd are part of primary key)

```
ItemId    ProdCd    ProdValue    ProdCurrencyCd
123       Shampoo   4.6          GBP           
124       Shampoo   5.8          GBP           
128       Shampoo   7.8          AUD           
125       Cashews   7.6          CAD           
125       ESwitch   17.6         CAD           
123       ESwitch   13.80        USD
```

**2.** **ItemDetails** (ItemId is primary key)

```
ItemId    OrderDate
123       2019-04-15
124       2017-07-15
125       2016-05-25
```

**3.** **ExchangeRates** (This table has exchange rates with respect to USD, meaning exchange rates only in term of USD to other currencies)

```
SourceCurrency    TargetCurrency    ExchangeDate    ExchangeRate
USD               GBP               2017-01-23        0.8039  
USD               GBP               2017-01-24        0.8034
USD               GBP               2017-01-25        0.7942
USD               CAD               2017-01-23        1.10
USD               CAD               2017-01-24        1.12
USD               CAD               2017-01-25        1.18
USD               AUD               2017-01-23        1.10
USD               AUD               2017-01-24        1.12
USD               AUD               2017-01-25        1.18`
```

**QUERY Expectation**
My client is providing me a prodCd and currency code e.g (`Shampoo|AUD`) and expecting to get result of all rows where prodCd is shampoo. **IMP NOTE:** If the ProdCd currency is different from requested currency, prodValues should convertd value.

Rules for conversion,

1. If ItemId's prodValue needs to be converted, use itemIds OrderDate from `ItemDetails` table and use `ExchangeRates` table to do the conversion (Join on OrderDate and Exchange Date)
2. (Part I don't know) If orderDate is not present in ExchangeRates table use the closest `ExchangeRate`. (Get Closest exchange date to the order date and use that exchange rate).
3. (Part I don't know) How can I write a query which covers all the conversion cases,
   3.1. Convert GBP product value to AUD? As all conversion rates are in terms of USD. I understand
   that I need to convert GBP to USD (Using USD to GBP) and then convert USD to AUD (using USD to AUD rate)
   3.2 User can request result in any currency. (Consider that exchange rate table has rates for all the currencies)

Here is what I got until now,

```
SELECT id.ItemId,    
       id.OfferingDate,     
       ipcv.Prodcd,     
Cast(Prodvalue AS DECIMAL(22, 8)) * er.ExchangeRate AS finalConvertedValue      
FROM   ExchangeRates er     
       JOIN ItemProdCodeValueMapping ipcv     
         ON er.SourceCurrency = ipcv.ProdCurrencyCd         
       JOIN Itemdetails id    
         ON ipcv.ItemId = id.ItemId
            AND id.OrderDate = er.ExchangeDate    
WHERE  er.TargetCurrency = 'AUD'     
       AND ProdCd = 'Shampoo'
```

My end goal is to have a query which will cover all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here how you can achieve this by using `cross apply`, second cross apply will give you the result in any provided currency:

if there is no provided currency exchange for given currency , the target currency would be in USD :

```
SELECT
    ipv.*
    , id.*
    , er.SourceCurrency
    , er.ExchangeDate
    , er.ExchangeRate
    , ipv.ProdValue * (1 / er.ExchangeRate)                    AS [ProdValue in USD]
    , er2.ExchangeDate [target exchnage date]
    , er2.ExchangeRate [target exchange rate]
    , ipv.ProdValue * (1 / ISNULL(er.ExchangeRate, 1)) * ISNULL(er2.ExchangeRate, 1) AS [ProdValue in target exchange]
FROM
    ItemDetail                    id
    JOIN ItemProdCodeValueMapping ipv
        ON ipv.ItemId = id.ItemId
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            *
        FROM
            dbo.ExchangeRates AS er
        WHERE
            er.TargetCurrency = ipv.ProdCurrencyCd
            AND er.SourceCurrency = 'USD' -- to avoid converting USD
        ORDER BY
            ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, ExchangeDate, id.OrderDate))
    ) er
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            *
        FROM
            dbo.ExchangeRates AS er_target
        WHERE
            er_target.TargetCurrency = 'CAD'
        ORDER BY
            ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, er_target.ExchangeDate, id.OrderDate))
    ) er2
WHERE
    ipv.ProdCd = 'Shampoo'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ordered by the absolute value of DATEDIFF in the cross apply clauses? I fear this would take the conversion rate that is prior to the order date, even if there is a later date that is actually closer.

Comment: @RandomUser , yes , it would but this is what is in the requirement : '(Get Closest exchange date to the order date and use that exchange rate).'

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you for suggestion. I'm going to try this and get back to you. 
Note : I want get closest exchange rate only if for a given OrderDate exchange rate is not available in ExchangeRates table

Comment: @eshirvana Correct me If i'm wrong, the query you wrote will always get closest exchange rate ? (Even when exchange is available on given orderDate, which I dont want).
Also, If ProdCurrencyCd is already in USD then won't this line produce wrong result?
ipv.ProdValue * (1 / er.ExchangeRate) * er2.ExchangeRate AS [ProdValue in target exchange]

Comment: @Ami if by closest exchange rate you mean the closest exchange date to the order date , yes , that's what the query does , that translate to if there is a exchange date on the same day as order date , this the closest one , another example if there is an exchange date the day before order date and another one 5 days after order date , the closest one is the 2 days before .

Comment: @ami dis some minor changes to show current.y usd currency product in target exchange column and for this ipv.ProdValue * (1 / er.ExchangeRate) * er2.ExchangeRate AS [ProdValue in target exchange] formula , it should be ok ,since the exchange rate is from usd to other curriencies

Comment: @eshirvana I think there are couple of issues in query. 
1.It's not handling the case when ProdValue is already in USD . It is converting those records to requested currency and then again converting to requested currency.

2. When ProdValue is in GBP, its usd conversion is wrong. Its converting to requested currency. 
Here are the results which I could add find
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oj3CN9UKQe0ElQvvJW2-YjpbW7aL62ZRkXAevwIJJ88/edit#gid=0

Shoud we do this?
1. First convert USD prodValue to requested currency
2. Union  with Non USD prod value to requested currency

Comment: @ami why you have non USD as source in your exchange sample data , you should only have one currency as source,  that’s why this query converts usd too , in your original question you only mentioned usd as source

Comment: @eshirvana Sorry for the late reply. Ah yes, thank you for pointing that. You are right I had mentioned in the post about USD as a source. I will update the post removing this condition. That being said I modified your query to consider that and testing with it.

Comment: @ami - yes , I updated  my answer to avoid converting USD

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you for your help. I accepted it as a answer.

Comment: @Ami glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

the other way of doing this, You could create a join with exchange table mapping target currency and get the same results

```
 DECLARE @Prodcd nvarchar(30);  
 DECLARE @TargeCurrency nvarchar(30);  

 SET @Prodcd = 'Shampoo ';
 SET @TargeCurrency = 'CAD';
 select ItemDetails.ItemId,Prodcd,ItemProdCodeValueMapping.ProdValue,
 ProdCurrencyCd,ItemProdCodeValueMapping.ProdValue,ItemDetails.Orderdate
    ,(ItemProdCodeValueMapping.ProdValue *(1/ExchangeRates.ExchangeRate)) * TargetCurrency.ExchangeRate finalConvertedValue   

 from ItemProdCodeValueMapping 

 inner join ExchangeRates on ExchangeRates.TargetCurrency = ItemProdCodeValueMapping.ProdCurrencyCd

 inner join ItemDetails on ItemProdCodeValueMapping.ItemId = ItemDetails.ItemId and ItemDetails.Orderdate = ExchangeRates.ExchangeDate

 inner join (select top 1 TargetCurrency,ExchangeRate,ExchangeDate from  ExchangeRates where 
    TargetCurrency = @TargeCurrency order by ExchangeDate desc) as   TargetCurrency  on TargetCurrency.ExchangeDate <= ItemDetails.Orderdate
 
 where Prodcd = @Prodcd
```

Comment: there might be no currency exchange rate at the same date as the order date , so that is the challenge . your query won't work if there is no currency exchange rate for that date

Comment: hmm, I was thinking if we remove top 1 then should work right, so we are checking TargetCurrency.ExchangeDate <= ItemDetails.Orderdate, it would pick equal or less that that date, if does not exists for sure we can go and  last available rather recent one.